# Which WCF method caused service activation?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, activation

After an IIS reset, no `w3wp.exe` processes are running. I launch a debugger in the override of my `ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration` method.

When the breakpoint is hit, I'd like to know which method invocation caused the service to be activated? `OperationContext.Current` is still null.

Is there a way to find this? Is there another global structure that contains this information?

Comment: How do you know that a WCF component was activated already. What if the IIS does not reach that point because it is damaged on a deeper level?

Comment: No, there's nothing damaged. I know which service I am in and have hit the breakpoint in the debugger. But at this point, the service endpoints are being configured. I just want to know what methods is called, activating the service, from inside the ApplyConfiguration method.